# SoX, how to apply multiple processing to one file?

Tags: sox

How do I apply norm and convert to one file in a single command (pipeline?)

`sox -S -c 2 | norm -3 input.mp3 output.mp3`  something like this maybe?

basically I want to convert the input.mp3 to 2 Channels and Normalize it to -3 in the same command?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
sox -S input.mp3 Output.mp3 channels 2 norm -3
```

This worked.